# Is it safe to take Magnesium pills (dissolve in water) if you have Gastritis?

Tags: digestion, magnesium, dissolve, gastritis

It seems that magnesium helps tremendously with anxiety. However, I do get a little pain in my stomach after drinking it. Is it safe for an inflamed stomach lining to drink magnesium supplements?